# How to setup gedit to 'continue where I left'?

Tags: gedit, gedit-plugin

How to setup gedit to 'continue where I left', open all the files closed previously? Any gedit plugins?

I know at least one trick, use an alias for `gedit < file1 > < file2 > ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two plugins I know of for doing this Restore Tabs plugin, and Session Saver plugin

you can find a link to Restore Tabs here: https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins#third_party

The Session saver comes with the gedit-plugins package from Ubuntu's repositories.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me now in 2021 but I found this plugin that does work in gedit 3.38.0 (Ubuntu 20.10).

Ex-Mortis: https://github.com/jefferyto/gedit-ex-mortis

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third-party gedit plugin: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ThirdPartyPlugins

Depending on your gedit version, I know about these plugins that can help you: Restore Tabs, Session Saver and Ex-Mortis.

For gedit 41.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 I use **Ex-Mortis**

1. Download the latest release and extract:
   https://github.com/jefferyto/gedit-ex-mortis/releases/latest
2. Copy plugin files:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
cp -r ex-mortis ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
cp ex-mortis.plugin ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
```

3. Restart gedit, then activate the plugin in the Plugins tab in gedit's Preferences window.
4. Activate "Restore windows between sessions" from Ex-Mortis plugin's Preferences.
5. Restart gedit again.